# 'opposite' of 'déjà vu'

Tags: single-word-requests

Recently while driving to the store (a path I have taken hundreds of times before), I was suddenly struck by a feeling that was similar to déjà vu, but in reverse.  Specifically, where *déjà vu* is the feeling "I have seen this before", I was struck by the odd feeling that everything seemed extremely unfamiliar (even though I know the roads well).

Is there a word to describe this "opposite to déjà vu" feeling?

Comment: I've heard it jokingly referred to as "Vuja De," but my only sources for this are Urban Dictionary and a George Carlin bit.

Comment: [O God, where am I?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WfX7JvU-50c)

Comment: There should be a word for that uncanny feeling.

Comment: Not remembering a place you've been many times before? Amnesia.

Comment: Having Brain Damage?

Comment: The various "vu"s are described nicely in Catch 22, in the scene where the chaplain sees a naked man in a tree at Snowden's funeral. See http://www.shmoop.com/catch-22/absurdity-quotes-7.html

Comment: I can induce this feeling by remembering a familiar place the way I saw it as a kid.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In French, we say 'jamais vue', and [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamais_vu) shows that the term *jamais vu* has also been adopted into English, mirroring *déjà vu*.

We use *jamais vu* to describe the fact that something has already happened to someone, but he feels like it's the first time.

I often experience the feeling myself when I'm concentrating on a particular word; if I keep repeating it, it begins to feel weird, as if it's not really the right word to use.

Comment: Yes, you can study this by repeating a given word aloud, and after the twentieth repetition it begins to sound like something in a foreign language.

Comment: Sometimes when I spell words, they just **look** wrong, even though they're clearly spelled correctly. That being said, I'm not sure I'd agree this phrase is quite idiomatic in English yet.

Comment: @DavidPugh There's a name for that, too; "Semantic satiation".

Comment: Yes, I have heard "jamais vu" a number of times, starting maybe 20 years ago.  It was the term that came to mind when I saw the question title.

Comment: Kim Stanley Robinson uses the expression 'jamais vu' in several of his novels (_Blue Mars_ and _Galileo's Dream_).

Comment: I don't quite agree with your interpretation of the use of the phrase in French. We say “jamais vu” to mean that we have actually never seen something. Even the phrase “déjà vu” isn't commonly used in its English or German sense of an unexplained and diffuse feeling of knowing something you can't be sure of having actually seen. It's much more matter-of-fact in French, like having seen a movie or not, and rarely if ever as a substantive (whereas Germans can say something like “I have a déjà-vu”).

Comment: (I think it's a good suggestion however but mostly by analogy with the English *déjà vu*, not because it's used in French)

Answer (score 7):

A person may be described / describe themselves as feeling **detached from reality**, when they realise that the familiar suddenly feels weirdly alien.

[SymptomChecker](http://symptomchecker.webmd.com/multiple-symptoms?symptoms=emotional-detachment%7Cfeeling-of-being-detached-from-reality%7Cfrightening-thoughts%7Cimpulsive-behavior&symptomids=440%7C371%7C427%7C265&locations=2%7C2%7C2%7C2) lists quite a few mental disorders which may have this sensation as a symptom, but I'm sure most people have the occasional manifestation, and getting on with everyday life soon corrects one's 'normality settings'.

Comment: +1 I don't understand the downvote, this seems a perfectly reasonable answer to me.

Comment: @Mynamite The above is not as specific as Jaro's. But I'll go with your judgement of relevance:)

Answer (score 7):

The jamais vu experience is similar to **[alienation](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/alienation)**.

The Latin word for alien is alienus, "belonging to another." ***That idea of not belonging, or not fitting in, gave rise to the Latin verb alienare***, "to estrange," which alienation comes from.

([vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/alienation))

Answer (score 0):

There is also something known as "proprioception", that allows your brain to take ownership of your body. Think of phantom limb syndrome. One trick psychologists use to test this is to have a subject lay their arm on a table. The subject's real arm is then hidden behind a cloth or partition, and a fake arm is placed approximately where the real arm should be. The psychologist will then apply some kind of pressure, or a pin prick to the subject's real but still hidden arm, and simultaneously do the same to the fake arm. Eventually, the subject's brain will "take ownership" of the fake arm, due to it's confusion about the visual stimuli and the tactile stimuli. So your brain can feel alienated in a usually familiar setting, but can also become alienated from your own body.